# Career path for experienced full stack web developer

Tags: career-development, software-development, career-switch

Background: I'm self-taught and have worked as a full stack JavaScript developer in small teams/freelance for about 5 years, starting from basic JS projects and picking up skills as required by projects. Over time that's amounted to a skillset that will get just about any small-medium scale web app project done from scratch to deployment. Additionally, in the last project I got the opportunity to learn a fair bit about DevOps and automation over 6 months to get an app with a fair amount of traffic running and scaling smoothly on a modern Kubernetes stack in the cloud, which I also enjoyed doing.

What I'm struggling with is my next move. I would like to work on larger projects, in bigger teams, rather than small startups and MVP-type projects, as that seems necessary to one day graduate to some sort of "architect" role which, while vague to me at the moment, does seem appealing. But I find that those job listings typically require a more narrow focus - front end, back end or DevOps.

In front end (I'm using React) I think I've relied too much on working with premade UI component libraries and don't really have a solid grasp of modern CSS myself. Understanding of performance profiling and optimization also feels underdeveloped due to lack of necessity in projects. In back end I can get any kind of database and API running but systematically modelling or optimizing them is a mystery to me. In DevOps I'm basically a hobbyist as I don't have much background in fundamentals like networking and security unlike people who go into the path from a sysadmin background. And since junior DevOps doesn't exist this seems like a no-go for now.

I think I might have spread myself too thin and lack deep domain knowledge required for large projects where a high degree of optimization is needed. But applying for slightly above entry level jobs with 5 years of experience just looks weird.

I understand that eventually I need to fill my gaps in the fundamentals across all of these domains if I want to aim for an architect role but what would make sense as the next step in my employment and how do I frame my "generalist" experience to get my foot in the door?

Comment: I'd be happy to chat with you about your question. I have set up a room here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111360/chat-with-demiters

Comment: I changed "generalist" to "full stack web" developer because "generalist developer" is, well, too general and it sounds like most of your experience is in building web applications. If you don't believe this description to be accurate, feel free to update.

Comment: @AffableAmbler you're right, no problem